# AWS IOS SDK Error Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services

I get this error after using cocoapods with AWS SDK IOS:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AWSInfo", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libAWSCognitoIdentityProvider.a(AWSCognitoIdentityProviderService.o)
      objc-class-ref in libAWSIoT.a(AWSIoTDataManager.o)
      objc-class-ref in libAWSIoT.a(AWSIoTDataService.o)
      objc-class-ref in libAWSIoT.a(AWSIoTManager.o)
      objc-class-ref in libAWSIoT.a(AWSIoTService.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own problem. 
When i created the project i selected to include unit tests for the project.
For whatever reason this conflicted with the cocoapod installation. When i created a new project without unit tests everything compiled correctly.
This could be a conflict between the two or I did not configure something properly either way it seems like units tests and cocoapods need some extra tinkering with.